# Jquery on form data input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im using Jquery to trigger AJAX to retrieve data from database on a realtime basis as the user inputs data into a form containing 5 input fields.

I currently have

```
$("#searchtype, #searchtext, #searchtag, #daterangefrom, #daterangeto").on("load change paste", function(){


});
```

This works great when someone changes a field but it doesnt trigger on load of the page ... the fields are populated from the last known data stored in a session variable when the page is reloaded, and I need the AJAX function to call on this reload too !!

I thought the "load" in the .on would have done this but apparently not

TIA

Comment: `$("#searchtype, #searchtext, #searchtag, #daterangefrom, #daterangeto").on("load change paste", function(){}).trigger('change');`

Comment: @cale_b you can remove the `load`

Comment: OK that runs the function on load, but its not running on change or paste now.

Comment: UPDATE: it is running on change but only when the field looses focus ... I need it to trigger as each letter is typed

Comment: Use `keyup` instead of `change`

Comment: Sorry ... no change using keyup, still only updates on blur of form input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your call like so:

```
$("#searchtype, #searchtext, #searchtag, #daterangefrom, #daterangeto").on("keyup paste", 
    function() {
         // Your code here
    }
).trigger('keyup');
```

`change` only triggers on blur, so remove it.
`keyup` triggers with every keypress.
`load` doesn't apply to this element.

Chaining `trigger('keyup')` will cause it to trigger your function immediately.

Also, consider adding a universal class to all of these elements, so you don't have to address them individually by id:

```
$(".action-ajax-call").on("keyup paste", 
    function() {
         // Your code here
    }
).trigger('keyup');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had t readd the change as I have dropboxes in the form and they werent triggering, but apart from that all seems good.